# Spring Server with H2 Database SchemaUpdate HHH000299

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa, h2

I have a Spring Server using JPA, Hibernate and H2 as database.

My `application.properties` is:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:/xxx/database;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql: true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=error
spring.datasource.username=xxx
spring.datasource.password=yyy
```

All is working perfectly until I add a new column in a table.

I do it with the H2 console:

[image: H2 console]

I added the new column using this syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE POINT ADD COLUMN USEDMAP BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE
```

After that, I run the Spring Server for the first time and all works perfectly.
**The problem comes when I stop the Server and start it again** . This Error message appears:

```
12:27:02.248 ERROR 11895 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000299: Could not complete schema update

org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Unique index or primary key violation: "PRIMARY KEY ON """".PAGE_INDEX"; SQL statement:
ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.POINT_PARAMANSWER ADD CONSTRAINT PUBLIC.FK_LE0OSMY3PLR32FRROOR04SN01 FOREIGN KEY(POINT_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.POINT(ID) NOCHECK [23505-176]
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:344)
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:178)
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:154)
at org.h2.index.PageDataIndex.getNewDuplicateKeyException(PageDataIndex.java:166)
at org.h2.index.PageDataIndex.add(PageDataIndex.java:144)
at org.h2.store.PageStore.addMeta(PageStore.java:1808)
at org.h2.index.PageBtreeIndex.<init>(PageBtreeIndex.java:64)
at org.h2.table.RegularTable.addIndex(RegularTable.java:235)
at org.h2.command.ddl.AlterTableAddConstraint.createIndex(AlterTableAddConstraint.java:280)
at org.h2.command.ddl.AlterTableAddConstraint.tryUpdate(AlterTableAddConstraint.java:205)
at org.h2.command.ddl.AlterTableAddConstraint.update(AlterTableAddConstraint.java:73)
at org.h2.engine.MetaRecord.execute(MetaRecord.java:59)
at org.h2.engine.Database.open(Database.java:719)
at org.h2.engine.Database.openDatabase(Database.java:260)
at org.h2.engine.Database.<init>(Database.java:254)
at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:57)
at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:164)
at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSessionAndValidate(Engine.java:142)
at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:125)
at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:27)
at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:331)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:107)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:91)
at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:74)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:278)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:182)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:701)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:635)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:486)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:144)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:116)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:103)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:127)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:139)
at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.java:51)
at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:194)
at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:178)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:522)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1859)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:852)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:845)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:398)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:844)
at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:152)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:338)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:634)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:444)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:299)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:129)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1481)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1145)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1069)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:967)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:543)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1145)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1069)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:967)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:543)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:201)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:534)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:523)
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.AutowiredWebSecurityConfigurersIgnoreParents.getWebSecurityConfigurers(AutowiredWebSecurityConfigurersIgnoreParents.java:52)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectiveMethodExecutor.execute(ReflectiveMethodExecutor.java:112)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:129)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.access$000(MethodReference.java:49)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference$MethodValueRef.getValue(MethodReference.java:342)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:88)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:120)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:242)
at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.evaluate(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:161)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.evaluateBeanDefinitionString(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1412)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:982)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:967)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:616)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:368)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:201)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:176)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAsRegistrationBean(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:141)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAsRegistrationBean(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:136)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAdaptableBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:119)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init>(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:69)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:216)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext$1.onStartup(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:202)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.ServletContextInitializerLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent(ServletContextInitializerLifecycleListener.java:64)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5380)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This error is showing some issue with other variable `paramanswer` in the same table `Point` which was not modified.

My `Point` java class  is:

```
@Entity
public class Point {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
     long id;


    @ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @Column(columnDefinition="VARCHAR(10000)")
    Map<Long, String> paramanswer = new HashMap<Long, String>();


    long projectid;


    double latitude;
    double longitude;

    boolean verified_gps;

    boolean current;

    boolean readytosend;

    String name;
    String address; //INCLUDING ADDRESS, NUMBER AND NEIGHBOURHOOD
    String city;
    String state;
    String country;
    @Size(max=10000)
    String description;
    long date;
    boolean android_received;
    boolean edited;
    long pointtype;

    String researcher;

    boolean usedmap;


    public Map<Long, String> getParamanswer() {
        return paramanswer;
    }


    public void setParamanswer(Map<Long, String> paramanswer) {
        this.paramanswer = paramanswer;
    }


    public Point()
    {}

    public boolean isUsedmap() {
        return usedmap;
    }


    public void setUsedmap(boolean usedmap) {
        this.usedmap = usedmap;
    }


    public long getPointtype() {
        return pointtype;
    }


    public void setPointtype(long pointtype) {
        this.pointtype = pointtype;
    }


    public boolean isEdited() {
        return edited;
    }


    public void setEdited(boolean edited) {
        this.edited = edited;
    }


    public boolean isReadytosend() {
        return readytosend;
    }


    public void setReadytosend(boolean readytosend) {
        this.readytosend = readytosend;
    }


    public long getDate() {
        return date;
    }


    public void setDate(long date) {
        this.date = date;
    }


    public boolean isCurrent() {
        return current;
    }


    public void setCurrent(boolean current) {
        this.current = current;
    }


    public List<Long> getIdsurveys_list() {
        return idsurveys_list;
    }


    public void setIdsurveys_list(List<Long> idsurveys_list) {
        this.idsurveys_list = idsurveys_list;
    }





    public boolean isVerified_gps() {
        return verified_gps;
    }


    public void setVerified_gps(boolean verified_gps) {
        this.verified_gps = verified_gps;
    }




    public String getResearcher() {
        return researcher;
    }


    public void setResearcher(String researcher) {
        this.researcher = researcher;
    }


    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }


    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public long getProjectid() {
        return projectid;
    }


    public void setProjectid(long projectid) {
        this.projectid = projectid;
    }




    public double getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }


    public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }


    public double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }


    public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }





    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }


    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }


    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }


    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }


    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }


    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }


    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }


    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }


    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }


    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }


    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }


    public boolean isAndroid_received() {
        return android_received;
    }


    public void setAndroid_received(boolean android_received) {
        this.android_received = android_received;
    }



}
```

Why is trying to update this `paramanswer` variable which was never modified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you are   adding new column manually when using hibernate.ddl-auto=update ? Just add new boolean property into entity class and it should be added automatically. Or don't use auto update DDL strategy.